# Host Youtube API data on a database to avoid quota limitation

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are developing an android application which showcases the videos published by our channel on the application. 
We are simply using the DATA API to fetch the videos present in our playlist and display them in the App.

Since there is a limit on API quota of 10,000 units, I would like to host the data on a database which I can scale up to 200,000 calls per day,
as we are targeting an audience of around 250,000 users.
Is this process legal?

I have raised the quota extension request using the form https://support.google.com/youtube/contact/yt_api_form?hl=en, but there is no significant progress.

Please guide me if I am missing something here or is there better way to approach the problem.

Comment: Hi any update on this? I'm planning to do the same but not sure storing the  API data (youtube data API search  response only snippet details) make any violation on legal contract "https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms/developer-policies"

Comment: @Sam I have been storing the youtube API data and refreshing it in an interval of 5 min(not storing historical data), I have not faced any issues till now. I think storing the snippet data should not be an issue.

Comment: thanks, a lot for your answer. really appreciate,